# getting Error in magento

Tags: javascript, php, magento

When I go to [my website](http://www.ageeyewear.com) I receive the following error (I downloaded this error file from the var folder):

> a:5:{i:0;s:88:\"Cannot send headers; headers already sent in
>   /home/eyewear/public_html/index.php, line 1\";i:1;s:943:\"#0
>   /home/eyewear/public_html/lib/Zend/Controller/Response/Abstract.php(115):
>   Zend_Controller_Response_Abstract->canSendHeaders(true)
>
> #1 /home/eyewear/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1246):
>   Zend_Controller_Response_Abstract->setHeader(\’Content-Type\’,
>   \’text/html; char...\’)
>
> #2 /home/eyewear/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(80):
>   Mage_Core_Model_App->getResponse()
>
> #3 /home/eyewear/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Url/Rewrite.php(204):
>   Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->getResponse()
>
> #4 /home/eyewear/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(166):
>   Mage_Core_Model_Url_Rewrite->rewrite()
>
> #5 /home/eyewear/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354):
>   Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
>
> #6 /home/eyewear/public_html/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
>
> #7 /home/eyewear/public_html/index.php(105): Mage::run(\’\’, \’store\’)
>
> #8 {main}\”;s:3:\"url\”;s:1:\"/\”;s:11:\"script_name\”;s:10:\"/index.php\”;s:4:\"skin\”;s:7:\"default\";}

Before I got this error, I was optimizing the website by minifying CSS and one .js file. This error occurred soon after, so I reverted back to original unminified js and the error still remains.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please give more clear info

Comment: need to explain little bit more

Comment: Please give reasons for downvote..it will help me

Comment: Check your "line 1" in /home/eyewear/public_html/index.php -- I think you have something, like "echo .." there

Answer (score 0):

a:5:{i:0;s:88:\"Cannot send headers; headers already sent in /home/eyewear/public_html/index.php, line 1\";i:1;s:943:\"#0 /home/eyewear/public_html/lib/Zend/Controller/Response/Abstract.php(115): Zend_Controller_Response_Abstract->canSendHeaders(true)

Check your file index.php line 943.

I has generated some content e.g echo or some html output.When an html output is genertaed header is created.
once header is created a redirect will not work.